# Application icon badge clears briefly, but the badge number returns within seconds in GameKit Turn-Based app

Tags: ios, cocoa, game-center, gamekit

I would like to clear the application icon badge each time the user opens the app.  In my app, I clear the badge with the following code:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
```

I put this code in both `- (void) applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication*)application` and `-(void) applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication*)application`.  I've also registered for remote notifications in `- (void) applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication*)application` before running the above code to clear the badge.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge)];
```

If I launch the app, then return to the Home screen, I see that the app's badge has been cleared, but it returns within a second or two to the exact same value it was before it was cleared.

I am not using Local or Push notifications myself, but rather GameKit is using them because it's a Turn-Based match.  When certain events happen (such as it becomes the local player's turn in  a match), a push notification is sent to their device.

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Were you able to resolve/debug this issue?

Answer (score 2):

This is not a solution for the problem but my observations I have made:

First my game was a TurnBasedMatch from GameKit but I had to change to a normal match, so I think I have to go through the code once more to check if i can find the annoying notifications GameKit sends.

Anyway it is definitely GameCenter:
I have two testaccounts, one running on my iPhone, one in the simulator. When I switch these, the "BageCount" also change. In my AppDelegate I set it to -1 (with 0 it doesn't work for me):

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = -1;
```

The AppBage disapears for 1-2 seconds and then comes back.

One way or another there must be a solution to clear these notifications out of the "GameCenter - NotificationCenter"!

Answer (score 1):

I saw a similar problem today on my device. I noticed that the device I had this problem on was on my company's VPN. After turning off the VPN connection, that badge cleared once and for all. I guess the device was unable to communicate with APNS during the process of the clear.

Not a convincing answer but I haven't the problem ever since.

Comment: Thanks for your input.  I'm not on a VPN, but the problem persists.  I am hoping it's either related to the fact that I'm using a sandbox account or I'm playing between my device and the simulator.

Comment: Actually the problem was not related to VPN at all. The badges are back for me. This seems like an iOS bug, what version of iOS are you testing on?

Comment: My device is on 5.0.1, Xcode 4.2.  I'm seeing the wrong banner on both the device and the simulator.